# Can I describe a shared variable in multiple C++ functions that can be called in Octave?

Tags: c++, octave

Is it possible to keep a state variable that is shared by multiple C++ functions called by Octave? I tried to explain what I am doing below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <octave/oct.h>
#include "stdlib.h"

int x = 0;

DEFUN_DLD(foo, args, , "foo"){
    x++;
    std::cout << "foo=" << x << "\n";
    octave_value_list retVal = ovl(x);
    return retVal;
}

DEFUN_DLD(bar, args, , "bar"){
    x++;
    std::cout << "bar=" << x << "\n";
    octave_value_list retVal = ovl(x);
    return retVal;
}
```

After I compiled the above .cpp file with mkoctfile, I am able to call them in Octave. My expectation from this code is incrementing the global variable x by 1 at every call of foo and bar. Apparently foo and bar functions recognizes x in different contexts. When I call foo and bar, both functions print 1 to the screen. Is there any way to define a common variable that can be reached by both functions?

By the way, I simplified the example by changing the type of x. I know that I can return it to Octave and feed both functions with the updated value of x. However, the type of x is actually a struct that I could not achieve to return to Octave.

Comment: This example works for me. After compiling your code with `mkoctfile` I call `foo` three times, and then when I call `bar` the first time I get back `4`.

Comment: The problem with global variables like this is that their value gets lost when the extension module is unloaded. In MATLAB there is a mexLock function to avoid unloading the MEX-file. Not sure but I presume there’s something similar in Octave.

Comment: @carandraug how could it be possible :) what version of octave do you use? Are your compilation commands different from these:
mkoctfile -c sandbox.cpp 
mkoctfile -o foo sandbox.o
mkoctfile -o bar sandbox.o

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have tried to use mlock function that prevents the function to be removed from memory in .cpp file by defining DEFMETHOD_DLD and calling interp.mlock(). It did not work. AFAIK there is no mexLock function in Octave.

Comment: @montekristo_07 I just did `mkoctfile path_to_cc.cc` and the in Octave used `autoload` to specify on which oct file the `foo` and `bar` functions are. It's good practice to name the oct file with at least one of the functions on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information in the comments, you compiled like so:

```
mkoctfile -c sandbox.cpp
mkoctfile -o foo sandbox.o
mkoctfile -o bar sandbox.o
```

Instead you should be doing this:

```
mkoctfile sandbox.cpp -o sandbox
ln -s sandbox.oct foo.oct
ln -s sandbox.oct bar.oct
```

See the relevant page in the manual for more details: https://octave.org/doc/v6.1.0/Overloading-and-Autoloading.html#Overloading-and-Autoloading

Comment: So OP had created different .oct files for each of the two functions, and therefore the two functions didn't share the variable `x`. Makes sense!

Comment: Thank you!! I needed to change somethings but your answer provided me to figure it out. First, I had to call "ln" commands by system calls, because I am working in Windows. But, it did not work. After that I loaded those two functions separately with autoload. Now everything looks ok. I added these two lines instead of "ln" lines:
autoload("foo", "sandbox.oct"); 
autoload("bar", "sandbox.oct");

Comment: `autoload` (instead of symlinks) is what Octave does internally when there's more than a function in a single oct file. You add a `PKG_ADD` file in the same directory with the `autoload` commands which Octave will run when that directory gets added to the path

Answer (score 2):

You can place the static variable in a shared library and create two .oct files that are linked against the shared library:

```
x.h
//---------------
extern int x;


x.cc
//---------------
#include "x.h"
int x = 0;


foo.cc
//---------------
#include <iostream>
#include <octave/oct.h>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "x.h"

DEFUN_DLD(foo, args, , "foo"){
    x++;
    std::cout << "foo=" << x << "\n";
    octave_value_list retVal = ovl(x);
    return retVal;
}


bar.cc
//---------------
#include <iostream>
#include <octave/oct.h>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "x.h"

DEFUN_DLD(bar, args, , "bar"){
    x++;
    std::cout << "bar=" << x << "\n";
    octave_value_list retVal = ovl(x);
    return retVal;
}
```

On Windows it is sufficient that all files to be on the same directory and use this:

```
g++ -shared -o libx.dll x.cc

mkoctfile -lx foo.cc
mkoctfile -lx bar.cc
```

On Linux you need to add the directory that contains `libx.so` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable and use this:

```
g++ -shared -o libx.so x.cc

mkoctfile -lx foo.cc
mkoctfile -lx bar.cc
```

If one of the functions is cleared the shared variable remains on memory. It is cleared only when both functions are cleared.

Comment: This also worked, too!!! Thank you very much. In addition to the above solution, this will be useful for larger codes. Btw, it was not sufficient to put the library file and *.cc files on the same directory, in Windows. So, I needed to add "-L./" flag at the end of mkoctfile commands. Maybe, I needed this change, because I call mkoctfile from the Octave's command window.

Comment: @montekristo_07 However, nothing prevent you from defining a custom Octave data type that fits your needs instead of using static variables.

Answer (score 0):

There can be found different approaches in [Octave discussion group](https://octave.discourse.group/t/can-i-describe-a-shared-variable-in-multiple-c-functions-that-can-be-called-in-octave/777) for the future readers.